# Add unique constraint and deduplicate column data

Tags: database, postgresql, liquibase

I am working on a Spring project which uses PostgreSQL and Liquibase. I need to add a unique constraint to a specific column in a table. The table already has a lot of entries and some of them violate the new unique constraint.

Since the application is in production, dropping the table is not an option. I need to implement some sort of modification to the data in the column, so that duplicates get indexed (e.g. we have 2 entries with the value 'foo', after the operation these entries should look something like 'foo' and 'foo2').

So far I've only implemented the change which adds the unique constraint, but I have yet to implement this modification. Is there any functionality in either PostgreSQL or Liquibase which might address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an SQL `UPDATE` query (or queries) that will modify the database and implement the logic that updates duplicates and sets unique values to them.

Then use change type [sql](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) in liquibase to instruct liquibase to run that query.